# No collision on Terrain in the shade of the trees

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Terrain with a path drawn using Path Painter. (The terrain is uneven and contains trees).

The trees next to the marked places are added manually as objects. The marked places show the shadow of these trees. I have a problem here. During the game, Cubes are loaded and fall from the top. At these points, sometimes there is no collision and the Cube falls below the Terrain.

In short, it is sometimes the Collider Terrain that does not work where the shade of the tree is. What could it be? After building the game there is also this problem. I ran Unity several times etc.

[image]

Comment: Does collision work in non-shaded areas all the time?

Comment: @Harry yes ....

Comment: Is the rigid body collision set to continuous?

Answer (score 0):

The shadows do not interact with the collision at all. Are the cubes moving too fast? When a Rigidbody is not set to continuous as @harry said, sometimes the physics engine can 'miss' that they were supposed to collide.